# Storing of string literals in consecutive memory locations

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, pointers

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main() {

    char *s[] = {"cricket","tennis","football"};

    printf(" String are: \n\n");
    printf("  %s \n", *(s));
    printf("  %s \n", *(s+1));
    printf("  %s \n", *(s+2));
    printf("  \n\n");

    printf("  Starting locations of the string are: \n\n");

    printf("  %d\n",*(s));
    printf("  %d\n",*(s+1));
    printf("  %d\n",*(s+2));
    printf("  \n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
String are: 

cricket 
tennis 
football 


Starting locations of the string are: 

134514112
134514120
134514127
```

s is a array of character pointers. s has three elements and each of them are storing the starting address of the string literals.i.e. s[0] is a pointer pointing to the starting address of "cricket". etc..

My question is :

By observing these addresses we can see that second string is stored just after the null character of the first string. All three strings are stored in sequential form. Is this always true ?

Comment: @Shubham Question is not about compactness of array members but about storing of strings to which that pointers point.

Comment: Notice there are other string literals like `"  %d\n"` and `"  %s \n"`.

Comment: Why do you even care? Any access beyond an array is undefined behaviour.

Comment: No guarantees at all. Plus the compiler can optimize how string literals are stored, if it detects that you use the same strings several times - this is usually called "string pooling".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a linker decision - to store string literals tightly or not. There is no guaranties. Or even this may be done by compiler - it may create continuous data section that holds all involved literals. But nevertheless actual layout of that section is still implementation-specific and you shouldn't assume anything about it.

Comment: @Debashish There is nothing more to explain. If you want to know the details on specific system, you need to read your linker manual.

Comment: @Debashish: In short, it is not dictated by the language standard (neither C nor C++).

Comment: @Debashish: In addition, you mind find it interesting to know that if there are two identical literal strings in your code, then the linker might choose to generate only a single copy in the executable image (again, not guaranteed by the standard).

Comment: @barakmanos ...or if you have, e.g. `"string"` and `"larger string"`, it might recognise the redundancy and map the former to the equivalent address _within_ the latter. I'm pretty sure I've seen this happen. But it is equally as much of an implementation detail and not guaranteed by the language at all.

Comment: It's compiler, not linker.

Comment: There is no requirement for a linker in the C standard. And for actual implementations, it is not only the linker (iff there is one) involved.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: See my comment above. Compiler, linker, loader, startup-code, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I have an example for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

char    *s[] = { "ball", "football" };

int main( void ) 
{
    int i;

    for( i=0; i<2; i++ ) {
        printf( "%" PRIuPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)s[i] );
        // or printf( "%p\n", s[i] ); forr hex output
    }
}
```

If I compile and run that program with `gcc -O3` I get:

```
4195869
4195865
```

What happens here is that the optimizer merges both string literal to a single "football" so that `s[0]` becomes `s[1] + 4`.

That's only one example of what compiler / linker might decide on how to store string literals ...

Comment: Interesting, but the question was "is this always true?" not 'can you show me another example of this or something else happening'. This seems like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @underscore_t: I think  an example of the assumption being false is an answer -- it can't always be true. By the way, Id agree that this might be merely kind of a comment, but I thought the example might be helpful and you can't put that in  a comment readably

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour. And will fail definitively on IL32P64 systems like Windows. And the array declaration is pretty dangerous, at least error-prone. It relies on a C legacy.

Comment: @OIaf Good point. Why not just use `%p`, the designated format specifier for pointers? The pointer conversion here violates aliasing rules, and there's no need to.

Comment: @olaf Thaks you're right, In fact I have first testetd with `%p` and then changed the `printf()` to have decimal output like in the question. Well, now it's a cast to `intptr_t`

Comment: Seems better - `C99 says that any pointer type can be cast to uintptr_t (or its underlying type) and back to the original pointer type without loss of information or violation of the strict-aliasing rules.` So we logically presume the same for `intptr_`t. But `PRIuPTR` is for printing `uintptr_t`, which might not be well-defined. You probably need to change those both to match up. If you don't want to use `void *`, `uintptr_t` seems most sensible, as I've never understood `intptr_t` for anything other than temporarily stashing a pointer in a `int`... seeing as RAM addresses cannot be negative!

Comment: @underscore_d thanks again, I've made it `uintptr_t` to be sure

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt: Printing a pointer via `uintptr_t` cast is also not defined. Use `%p`, what is your problem with hexadecimal output? For pointers that is the most clear format. Decimal is close to nonsense.

Comment: @Olaf as I've already answered, I have no problem with hex but wanted to sty close to the original question. And could you pleas explain why the cast is not defined?

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt: Where did I say **the cast** is not defined (actually it is not defined how the pointer is converted to the integer, but that is irrelevant for the defined usage). You might want to read about `uintptr_t` before printing a pointer that way. Long story short: use `%p` **only** to print a **`void *`** **only**.

Comment: @Olaf I think I've got you now. So you mean the two integers printed don't neccessarily show the string addresses and especially, if they are consecutive or not, right?.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt: It is undefined. Just please read the standard!

Comment: @Olaf I agree just to use `%p` for clearest results and avoiding (more) odd conversions, but do you really mean that the standard `PRI?PTR` macros produce undefined behaviour when printing their corresponding `ptr_t` types? That sounds rather absurd. Why else would they exist? Surely they just map to the right specifier for the corresponding numeric type and print that. So if the conversion from real pointer to numeric value and back is well-defined, which it is, so must be printing said value. Sure, it's not required to be intuitive relative to memory layout/order, but I really doubt it's UB.

Comment: Notes: `uintptr_t` is an optional type.  Using `"%p"` does not necessarily print in hexadecimal - although that is common.  It is "implementation-defined manner"

Comment: @underscore_d: I also did not say that! Heck, why does nobody read trhe standard and what is guaranteed for `uintptr_t`? **Only** conversion forth and back is guaranteed. No arithmetics, no printing, no usage for later reference. They basically exist for non-portable arithmetic in very low-level functions where you really know what you are doing (and which should secured by platform assertions), and to allow passing a pointer or an integer (kind of "union light").

Comment: @Olaf Don't pawn this off as me "not reading the standard". I spend a possibly unhealthy amount of my time absorbing what is and is not standard in this language. I'm still waiting for you to explain why the `printf` format macros such as `PRIuPTR` exist in the same standard(!) header file if they invoke undefined behaviour. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cinttypes/ I'm sure the printed results are likely to be _implementation-defined_ and not necessarily reflect memory layout. But as part of a standard header, they simply cannot be _undefined_ in the sense of common parlance: invoking UB.

Comment: @underscore_d: And you should read comments carefully. Where exactly did I even mention the macros, less state they invoke UB? Oh, btw.: cplusplus.com does not define the standard (or did that change? Feel free to post the ISO message). Maybe you should read the **standard**?

Comment: Well, the fact that Ingo had corrected their answer to avoid obvious UB but you were still posting, vaguely, "It is undefined. Just please read the standard!" could mean a lot of different things. Then you seemed to indicate you were equally against the idea of printing by saying "**Only** conversion back and forth is guaranteed. No arithmetics, no printing", which given the use of "guaranteed" and past context sounds like you're saying something is UB... and the mention of "printing" implies you might've been responding to the `printf` macros. If you're saying something else, please, clarify.

Answer (score -1):

It will be totally compiler dependent. Compiler can take any address at the time execution started

Comment: What do you mean? Addresses of strings within the image are determined at compile time. Adjustment of address for relocation purposes is performed by the loader; the compiler has nothing to do with that.

Comment: yes adjustment of addresses is done when linker when it wants some memory location. and after that loader load that address from hard disk. And that is a phase of compilation. that is why I told it is compiler dependent

Comment: How does this relate to string literals and their positioning relative to one another? One would assume that the entire section wherein they are contained might have its address adjusted but that they would stick together relatively. Or do you have a specific answer to the question?

Answer (score -3):

Only static arrays are contiguous in memory. ex: char s[1024].

Comment: Are not _all_ arrays contiguous within themselves?  Perhaps show your answer as it relates to two or more arrays.

Comment: What does this mean? What happens to _non-`static`_ arrays? I think you're thinking of something different, or perhaps drawing inferences from one platform that aren't Standardised for all.

Comment: static keyword assume that your variable is global. it's mean that the max size of your array is not limited according to the stack size.

Comment: What relevance do allocation strategy or available memory have to whether any array is contiguous (A) within itself or (B) relative to other arrays? And does your "contiguous" here refer to A or B, anyway? A is always true. Other users have already noted that B is entirely implementation-defined.

Comment: nope, static memory allocation is compiler dependant, and you cannot assume any storage arrangement.